# How to handle sending and receiving multiple values between 2 tasks?

Tags: rust, channel, rust-tokio

I need to send and receive multiple values between 2 tasks. I am currently using tokio oneshot channel because I am only dealing with 2 tasks. But I can't seem to re-use the tx probably due to its one message limit. How is this situation handled usually?

- Do I create a new oneshot channel everytime? or is there a way to reuse the channel?
- Do I try packing all my interactions into 1 message and just do it once? -> seems very restrictive.
- Do I use other channel types?

Comment: Why are you using a oneshot channel if you want to send more than one message? From your vague description, you probably want a [mpsc](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/index.html) channel instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`tokio::sync::mpsc`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/index.html) channel should be used in this situation.

I suspect you're worried by the fact that it supports multiple senders, but its perfectly fine to use it when you only have one sender.

Comment: yep i guess that's what I worried about. I will give it a try thanks!